# How to make max price be required if min price entered?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

So basically it works like person inputs min price (but forgets to input max price) then he presses search (it won't search and a wording comes out beside the max price that asks him to input max budget.....

```
<form role="search" id="myform1" name="form" method="get" action="<?php echo home_url( '/properties/' ); ?>" >
    <div class="mini-field" id="minfield">
        <input input name="pricefrom" class="txt-field-input-mini formattingNumber" placeholder="Price from" style="width:159px;"id="min">
        <p><input input name="priceto" class="txt-field-input-mini formattingNumber" placeholder="Price to" title="Please input maximum price budget" style="width:159px;" id="max"></p>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="start-search-btn" id=search>Start Search<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/images/search-img-white.png"  alt="Start Search" class="start-search-img"/></button>
</form>
```

Comment: `if ($("#min").val()== "" || $("#max").val()==""){alert("fill details; return false")};` add this code before processing the form i.e. add this on $(form).submit(function(e){});

Comment: @GauravKalyan hello Thankyou for your reply . but when user not add min,price it will search, but when a user add or click the min,price the search will stop and it will require a max.price

Comment: @GauravKalyan <script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#myform1').on('submit', function() {  
            if ($('#min').val()== "" || $('#max').val()==""){
alert("fill details; return false")};
               
}
});
   });
</script> the script is not working...

Comment: Ok. I am going to write a complete answer below so that it will be useful and better understandable to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the Conditions like these:-

```
`if ($("#min").val()== ""){
    /*Do Your Search*/
}
else{
    if($("#min").val()!== "" && $("#max").val()!==""){
        /*Do Your Search*/ 
    }
}`
```

Update your code like this:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#myform1").submit(function(event){
       if ($("#min").val()== "" ){
          /*Do Your Search*/
       }
       else{
          if($("#min").val()!== "" && $("#max").val()!==""){
              /*Do Your Search*/ 
          }
          else{event.preventDefault();//this doesn't allow submit function to execute
              alert("Please Fill the details");
          }
       }
   });
```

Comment: what will be the starting script? should be like this ?<script> $(document).ready(function() { $('#myform1').on('submit', function() ??

Comment: it's just when i click "Min.Price only"then the "Max price will require" but if i dont click the min. price, it will continue to search. @GauravKalyan thankyou for helping me, im doing this a week ago :(

Comment: Updated the code a little bit more. It searches when you have not clicked the min price and it also searches when min price and max price is not empty. If I am missing any other condition, please do tell.

Comment: IT WORKS NOW!!! AND THIS IS WHAT IM TALKING ABOUT! THANKYOU AGAIN!!! THIS QUESTION SOLVED :)

Comment: Good to see your problem solved.  Please remember to mark the answer that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are triggering a 'submit' event, you MUST cancel it if you don't want the form to submit. (Building on Gaurav Kalyan's answer)

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#myform1').on('submit', function(e) {

        // If min value is set but NO max value is set, cancel the submit
        if ($('#min').val() && !$('#max').val()) { 
            e.preventDefault(); // Cancel the default event of submitting the form
            alert("fill details; return false"); 
        } 
    }); 
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: ill try this wait.. @iampueroo

Comment: "So basically it works like person inputs min price (but forgets to input max price) then he presses search (it won't search and a wording comes out beside the max price that asks him to input max budget....."  @iampueroo

Comment: it's just when i click "Min.Price only"then the "Max price will require" but if i dont click the min. price, it will continue to search.

Comment: Ah sorry. Updated. Now on submit, it checks to see if the ```$('#min')``` element has a value but the max does NOT, then it alerts the error and prevents the default submit event from propagating.

Comment: let me try please wait a sec.@iampueroo

Comment: IT WORKS NOW!!! AND THIS IS WHAT IM TALKING ABOUT! THANKYOU AGAIN!!! THIS QUESTION SOLVED :)

Comment: @Dmoz again - awesome! but please if you are satisfied with one of the answers, check the checkmark underneath its up/down arrows to mark it as the answer!